# Access a method in a Fragment from multiple adapters?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-adapter

I have a `MainActivity` activity with a `FoodOrderTotalFragment` which displays the total price of the food order, this fragment has 3 adapters (`IngredientsAdapter`, `SizeAdapter` and `AddonItemAdapter`) which present a list of `checkBoxItem` views that each has a different monetary value to each.

Each time I check or uncheck any of the `checkBoxsItem`s in any of the adapters I want the total price displayed in the `FoodOrderTotalFragment` to update accordingly. What is the propper way to create a method in the `shoppingCartFragment` that can be triggered from each of the adapters each time a `checkBoxItem` is checked or unchecked.

**I have tried:**

1. Setting the method as a `companion object` in the `FoodOrderTotalFragment`, but I have learned that this is not a good practice, besides it can't access not static variables such as a TextView.
2. I have tried creating a interface in the adapters an extending it in the `FoodOrderTotalFragment`, but I'm not sure implementing 3 different instances in the fragment is the most elegant solution.
3. Maybe passing the Fragment as a parameter when creating the adapters to access it's methods is the way to go here?

Comment: pass a lambda to the adapters and just invoke them from the adapter.

Comment: as @sonnet said above , using lambdas or (high order functions as parameters in your adapters) is a more cleaner way than No.2 (implementing interface) , you just take lambdas in your adapter like Adapter(count : Int , checkBoxListener(isChecked : Boolean) -> Unit )  where you call checkBoxListener() when checkBox is checked , and then implement this function when initializing your adapters